# Trying to create a case to identify multiple characters

Tags: java

I'm attempting to create a case that identifies every use of 'E' or 'e' in a string but am unsure how to format it correctly.

I've attempted separating 'E' and 'e' as seperate variables but this doesn't seem to work

The output should tell the user how many uses of 'e' or 'E' are in the string they entered, but I am just getting formatting errors. Additionally, if I limit it to either just 'e' or 'E' the program is able to work, however, I get a long string of numbers from it being counted in my for loop, is there any way to just display the final number from my for loop?

```
case 3:  String phrase;
     phrase = scan.nextLine();

     System.out.println("What is your sentence");
     phrase = scan.nextLine();

     int numOfE = 0;
     for (int i  = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++) {
         if (phrase.charAt(i) == 'e' or == 'E') {
             numOfE++;
         }
         System.out.println(numOfE);
     }
```

Comment: convert entire string to lower case, then you can run a mapping function or just a for loop for string.charset. if char == ‘e’, increment. does that solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
if (phrase.charAt(i) == 'e' or == 'E')
```

to

```
if (phrase.charAt(i) == 'e' ||  phrase.charAt(i) == 'E')
```

Also, move the line:

```
System.out.println(numOfE);
```

outside one more set of brackets. In total, it should look something like:

```
case 3:  String phrase;
    phrase = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("What is your sentence");
    phrase = scan.nextLine();

    int numOfE = 0;
    for (int i  = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++) {
        char ch = phrase.charAt(i);
        if (ch == 'e' ||  ch == 'E') {
            numOfE++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(numOfE);
```

Comment: Even better change it to `char ch = phrase.charAt(i); if (ch == 'e' || ch == 'E')...` this way you avoid the duplicated call to `charAt()`

Comment: Thanks, added that in! @John3136

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot! As a follow up question, I'm trying to use this as a method, but am getting an error about not having a return statement, how would I go about fixing this to still have the output be the same?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java 8, then this is another approach

```
long count = phrase.chars().filter(ch -> ch == 'e' ||  ch == 'E' ).count();
```